# Populating jQuery drop down menu items

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, shopify

Hello I am trying to basically feed my navigation into a jQuery drop down list, but can't get it to display anything... I have tried adding my link list near the bottom replacing:`nav a`.. or should I be creating a style in the css for `nav a` with my links at that location? Here is my full code:

```
   $("nav select").change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});

// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo("nav");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("nav a").each(function() {
 var el = $(this);
 $("<option />", {
     "value"   : el.attr("href"),
     "text"    : el.text()
 }).appendTo("nav select");
});
```

I am using the Shopify platform and intending this for a mobile version of a Navigation menu. If I could get any help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to bind the event to an element that doesn't yet exists, move the `change` binding after creating the select or you can just chain the calls like this:

```
// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo("nav").change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your speedily response! so after replacing that code snippet, and adding my linklist to the `nav a` it should then work? I apologize I am uneducated in Javascript.. Thanks again!

Comment: @Steven Yes it should work, here's a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/dTZem/, also I see you're new here, welcome! and if you haven't please read [this guide](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on voting/accepting answers

Comment: Ok so I copied the code the right way but still, the dropdown displays nothing and are blank. I substituted the URL but it just refreshes the page... Any idea? I am sorry to make this at all confusing.

Comment: @Steven how about you show exactly what you're doing? can you make a jsbin or jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Now that I think about it, Could it be because JQuery is not loading correctly? This is heading my asset page: `jQuery(function($){` while This `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js` Is loaded in the header...

Comment: @Steven use jsbin and put the complete code of your page, that fiddle looks exactly like the one I posted before

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KWf8C/ Ok sorry about that.. Here is the new fiddle code. It seems to work on there, but still not on the site..

Comment: I figured it out! It turns out later down the code i had another Jquery loading...  My mistake, and I have learned a lot here. Thank you guys so very much for being so helpful. I am appreciateive.

Comment: @Steven glad to hear you sorted things out, please take a moment to mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark next to it, this lets the community know your issue has been solved